# Flag for init polymer cli?

Tags: polymer, command-line-interface, polymer-cli

I looked at the `help` for `init` for the new [Polymer CLI](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/tools/polymer-cli) for but I could not see any flags to reduce the number of bower packages downloaded, especially if the `init` is for a new element, I would not really need `paper-ripple` by default or if I need it, I can add it later.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`paper-ripple` is a transitive dependency of `iron-component-page`, which is in the [element template's default `devDependencies`](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-cli/blob/a8afbdc/src/init/element/templates/bower.json#L10). The `iron-component-page` is intended for the element's demo page, which would make sense if you were going to publish this element standalone.

The `ElementGenerator` simply [copies files](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-cli/blob/a8afbdc/src/init/element/element.ts#L64-L71) from its [template directory](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-cli/tree/a8afbdc/src/init/element/templates), so you could just modify that directory in your installation, removing dependencies from `bower.json` as desired.

On my machine, I removed all dependencies from `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/polymer-cli/lib/init/element/templates/bower.json` so that it looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "<%= name %>",
<% if (description) { -%>  "description": "<%= description %>",
<% } -%>
  "main": "<%= name %>.html"
}
```

Now, the element generator outputs this:

> ```
> $ polymer init element
> info:    Running template element
> ? Element name x-bar
> ? Brief description of the element
>    create bower.json
>    create demo/index.html
>    create index.html
>    create README.md
>    create x-bar.html
>    create test/x-bar_test.html
>
> Project generated!
> Installing dependencies...
>
>
> I'm all done. Running bower install for you to install the required dependencies. If this fails, try running the command yourself.
>
>
>
> Setup Complete!
> Check out your new project README for information about what to do next.
> ```

Comment: You're not installing Polymer anymore, how are you running your element?

Comment: The OP wants to manually install the deps as needed instead of with every new element generation. I can see a scenario where the element is intended to be used inside the current Polymer app, where Polymer is already installed.